# Awk print every line x3 times?

Tags: awk

With this awk one-liner 
`awk '{lines[NR]=$0}{for(i=0;i<3;i++) print $lines[i]}`  awk.write

awk.write

```
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
but not 1
THIS is not
butbutbut ffff
second line
```

printed as

```
this line 1 no un1x
this line 1 no un1x
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
this lines 22 0
this lines 22 0
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
but not 1
but not 1
but not 1
THIS is not
THIS is not
THIS is not
butbutbut ffff
butbutbut ffff
butbutbut ffff
second line
second line
second line
```

However, it seems there is use of `$` working differently over-here, as without it running `lines[i]` i get

```
this line 1 no un1x


this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0

this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0

this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0

this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0

this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0

this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
```

The point being `lines[0]` returns empty results when the same run with `$lines[i]` it outputs as above shown in `printed as` section. Is there no better way of doing this I don't like use of `$` in this regard. Thanks.

Comment: In awk, think of `$` as a function to return the value of the given field. So `$lines[i]` acts like `getFieldValueForColumn(lines[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to use a loop to repeat each line `N` times, then you should change your script to this:

```
awk '{ for (i=0; i<3; i++) print }' file
```

The advantage of using a loop is that you can use a shell variable to define the number of times each line should be printed. You could even make it into a shell function:

```
repeat_line_n_times() {
    n=$1
    file=$2
    awk -v n="$n" '{ for (i=0; i<n; i++) print }' "$file"
}

repeat_line_n_times 3 file
```

Obviously you can "unroll" this loop and end up with a shorter script for low numbers of lines but this approach scales much better!

If you wish to store each line in an array (from your example it's not clear why that would be the case), then you should modify your script as follows:

```
awk '{ lines[NR] = $0; for (i=0; i<3; i++) print lines[NR] }' file
```

Note that all of the code is in the same `{ action }` block. Also, note that I'm using `lines[NR]` rather than `$lines[i]`, as per your attempt. The `$` is used to refer to a specific field in awk, so shouldn't be used in front of variables unless the variable contains the number of a field. Of course, I'm only using the `lines` array to illustrate how to do so correctly; as I showed in the first example, the default `print` (no arguments) works here because you're trying to print the current record `$0`.

Answer (score 5):

I would use `sed`:

```
sed 'p;p' file
```

You only need two `p` actions since `sed` will print the line already once by default.

---

With `awk` it can be:

```
awk '1;1;1' file
```

which is the same as:

```
awk '1{print}1{print}1{print}' file
```

or

```
awk '{print}{print}{print}'
```

---

Alternatively simply:

```
awk '{print;print;print}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`$` is used to access the fields in a single row, with the special case of $0 bing the whole row.

What is happening is that `lines[i]` is returning a string. `$x` requires the `x` to be an integer.  So the string is being implicitly cast to zero and you get three times `$0` being printed - 3 x the current row.

Without it, you are getting rows 0, 1 and 2 printed (once they've been read), but there is no row 0 in awk so that is being printed as a blank line.